# Google Chrome tabs titles are not completely visible (cut)

Tags: google-chrome

Starting from yesterday I've a weird problem with Google Chrome on my iMac 5k with Yosemite (updated).

[image: tab]

As you can see, the text is shifted down some pixel and the lower part is not visible.

Chrome is updated to the latest stable `43.0.2357.134 (64-bit)`, I have already tried to restart Chrome and the iMac itself.

I have even Chrome Canary and on that version everything works correctly.
On my MacBook Pro with Chrome stable everything works.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The problem is related to the San Francisco font on Yosemite, remove it and it get fixed

Comment: How do you remove it and how do you also use that font on other documents e.g. Xcode

Comment: You remove it like any other font in OS X. No need to explain.